# Assign arbitrary deep in object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically create an nested object

My current solution however seems a bit cumbersome

```js
output["USER_PROFILE"] = {};
output["USER_PROFILE"][this.userId] = userProfile;
```

Ideally i could just write something like:

```js
output["USER_PROFILE"][this.userId] = userProfile;
```

which obviously yields:
`Cannot set property '04c05a6a' of undefined`

Is there a way to tell javascript to create everything on the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the key inside the object literal:

```
output.USER_PROFILE = {
  [this.userId]: userProfile
};
```